# ISNULL with multiple Integer values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2014, isnull

My requirement is to pass input parameter with some Integers into DB to fetch the data. But in the front end, I'm checking if we didn't select any input data (Report type of application), NULL should pass else all the data or selected data should pass.

```
WHERE
    a.DateTime BETWEEN '2018-04-12 00:00:00' AND '2018-04-12 23:59:59' 
    AND ISNULL('0000441183344450,0000447769267501,0000447789917187',CallNumber) = CallNUmber
    AND ISNULL(CAST('1,2,3' AS INT), ID) = ID
```

In the above query `ISNULL(CAST('1,2,3' AS INT), ID) = ID` is causing an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2,3' to data type int

I know its very generic error but my requirement is to pass the selected Integer values or all values if the user didn't select any values in the input.

In the database, `ID` has an `int` datatype and if used with quote values (and `ISNULL('121','122',AgentSkillTargetID)=AgentSkillTargetID`) I'm getting an error

> The isnull function requires 2 argument(s)

In the same query

```
ISNULL('0000441183344450,0000447769267501,0000447789917187',CallNumber) = CallNUmber
```

is working, since the datatype of `CallNumber` is `varchar`.

Comment: Your query makes no sense and/or your UI logic is broken.  You can't compare a CSV string of numbers against a numeric column in SQL Server.

Comment: Are you looking for [`coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) ?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes coalesce worked in my case. Bad that I haven't used that one before. Thanks for the help and pls post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`isnull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) function is a t-sql function that can only accept two parameters. For returning the first non-null value from a larger list of parameters, use the ansi-complient [`coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) function instead. Some people might claim you should never use `isnull`, since it's not ansi complient. Personally, I don't think that it's a good enough reason. I think you should use the best tool available.

For more information, read the [Comparing `COALESCE` and `ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql#comparing-coalesce-and-isnull) section of the `coalesce` doc page.